# Couldn't add "Name" tag to resource "aws_eks_node_group" when creating a nodegroup in terraform

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform, tags, hashicorp

I am using terraform with AWS as a provider. I use terraform to create AWS resources through   Jenkins using a particular JenkinsJob.
I want to auto-populate the "Name" tag of ec2 node instances which gets created currently when using resource "aws_eks_node_group", but with no success. I see the ec2 instances are created with no name to it. I don't wish to manually update those ec2 instances in AWS console, but instead should get automated with "Name" tag.

Following is the example I used :

```
resource "aws_eks_node_group" "nodegroup" {

cluster_name   = var.cluster_names
disk_size      = var.node_disk_size
instance_types = var.node_instance_type
labels = {
"eks/cluster-name"   = var.cluster_names
"eks/nodegroup-name" = "some_value"
}
node_group_name = "some_value"
node_role_arn = var.node_roles
subnet_ids = flatten(\[var.private_subnet_id\])
tags = {
"eks/cluster-name"                = var.cluster_names
"eks/eksctl-version"              = "1.21"
"eks/nodegroup-name"              = "some_value "
"eks/nodegroup-type"              = "managed"
"eksctl.cluster.k8s.io/v1alpha1/cluster-name" = var.cluster_names
"Name" = var.cluster_names
}

scaling_config {
desired_size = var.node_desired_size
max_size     = var.node_max_size
min_size     = var.node_min_size
}
}
```

//Note: The value I use for var.cluster_names is as follows

```
variable "cluster_names"{
    type = string
}
```

I provide the default value with random cluster name in JenkinsJob as a parameter value.//

I tried adding "Name" tag, but couldn't auto-populate ec2 instances. I heard we can try using launch template to add "Name" tag, but I would like to know if there is any other way other than using launch template.

Comment: What value is assigned to `var.cluster_names`?

Comment: We have the value for var.cluster_names. But, the tag "Name" is not getting populated. It isn't being picked up with any value for any ec2 instances created.

Comment: The value I provided is of random cluster name. For example a string with value "cluster-name"

Comment: It depends on what type of the value is assigned to the variable. If it's a list for example, it will not work. Would you mind adding the value to the question?

Comment: I did make the edit to the query I posted above. I don't use list though as a value

Comment: Are you maybe using default tags on the provider level?

Comment: No, I haven't provided any tags on the provided level